# Check if iOS version is 3.0 or higher with PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ios, mobile-safari, user-agent

I need to check if an iOS device visiting my Website has iOS 3.0 or higher installed.
Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit of an older question, but I believe none of the answers currently given answer the question appropriately.

If you want to do something like

```
if(iOS_version > 3){
    // Open something
}
```

Then I believe you are looking for

```
if(/(iPhone|iPad|iPod)\sOS\s3/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // use apple maps
}
```

Where s3 is looking for iOS3. Change s3 to s9 to check for iOS9

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to check what browser/mobile device is accessing you site - then the answer is that you can use read the userAgent string and search for OS and the number. For example:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone **OS 4_0** like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7

and another useful online tool to check your browser UA is: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/

Comment: I would need something that works like this: ìf(iOS_Version >= 3.0) { redirect to other site } Is there a possibility to do that with userAgent???

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Either PHP or Javascript will do the trick. iOS devices report their iOS version in their `user-agent` string. Here are the Apple docs: [Using the Safari User Agent String](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW3). Some example `user-agent` strings might look like:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iOS 2_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/525.18.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.1.1 Mobile/XXXXX Safari/525.20
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.05 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X;  en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2  Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5
```

From there it's easy to see which version of iOS is being run.

Comment: I hope I do not sound stupid but how do I achieve this 3.0 or higher thing. Obviously I can check for specific iOS versions like 4_3_3 but I need to check for 3 or higher. Do I have to check for every single Version of iOS available?

Comment: @matteok Look at my answer below, it will answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `user-agent` which is send with the HTTP-request. This can then be processed by PHP.

See [this tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html) (note that this targets the iPad. But the iPhone should have something similar).